# What's the type of this function?

Tags: typescript

I would like to pass a function as argument, but I'm not able to figure out the type declaration, because it uses a syntax I'm not familiar with. I could use `any`, but I rather would like to avoid that.

The function in question is `mapStateToProps`. The goal is to pass the function itself as an argument in a type-safe way.

```
class Props {
    counterModel:CounterModel = null;
}
function mapStateToProps({counterModel}:Props) {
    return {
        counterModel
    };
}
```

The short form of the function is (if that helps in any way):

```
const mapStateToProps3 = ({counterModel}:Props) => ({counterModel});
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#function-types

Comment: Looks like `(p: Props)=>Props` to me, but I'm not sure if your class definition is complete enough for that to be the answer.  Does `Props` have other stuff in it?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks. `(p: Props)=>Props` is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `mapStateToProps` is `(arg: Props) => { counterModel: CounterModel }`.

If you want to use its type elsewhere, you can also just use the shortcut `typeof mapStateToProps` instead of rewriting it yourself manually.

Comment: Thanks you, this works. The comment of @jcalz with `(p: Props)=>Props` also works.